# Portable apps, Dropbox & default programs?

Tags: windows-7, dropbox, sublime-text-2, portable-apps

Currently I'm using Sublime Text 2 portable & I have put it inside dropbox to sync with my work PC. The problem is I can't set it as a default program to open HTML/CSS/PHP etc.. files, whenever I open the (open with) dialog & browse to choose Sublime it doesn't appear in the list & therefore I can't choose it. So does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: You should be able to select any program by selecting browse and then finding the executable.

Answer (score 2):

Hit the `Browse...` button...

[image: open with dialog]

and remember to check `Always use the selected program to open this kind of file`.

Comment: I know this & I tried it a couple of times. The problem was after selecting the .exe file it doesn't appear & I can select it.

I found a fix here http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/178066-open-add-program.html